# is there any way to create multiple buttons in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i want to create an option like button in p5.js web editor.how can i achieve it i want to build a simulation where user can click on that button to select input' i want to create multiple buttons or when anyone clicks the button more options comes out

````
var img1
let posX=0
let posY=0
let button;
const rightwall=350;

function preload(){
    img1=loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/master/resource/icon/Bird64.png")
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    button =createButton('CLICK ME');
    button.position(250,300);
    button.mousePressed(changeBG);
    noLoop()
}

function changeBG() {
    let val = random(255);
    background(val);
    if (playAnim) {
        noLoop();
        playAnim = false;
    } else {
        loop();
        playAnim = true;
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    fill('red');
    rect(320,75,170,160)
    fill('grey');
    rect(posX,170,70,30)
    
    image(img1,posX,posY-280,180,200)
    
    posX = constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
    posY = constrain(posX-1,posY,height-20)
    if (posX == rightwall-30) {
        posX=0
        posY=0
    }
}```
````

Comment: Are you looking for multiple canvases, each with certain buttons, or possibly a drop down list?  Clarify what you mean by 'when anyone clicks the button more options comes out'.

Comment: possibly a drop down list in p5.js only for single canvas

Answer (score 0):

The following demo will create a drop down list which will run in p5.js Web Editor.  This is the first conversion to p5.js and has not been extensively tested.

```
// Drop Down List parts => a.)display field, b.)arrow, c.)listItems
// Syntax: List(x, y, w, h, itemH, txtSize)

let list;
let selectedItem = -1;
let drop = false;
let items = ["Apples", "Peaches", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears" ];
let itemY = [];

class List {

  constructor(x, y, w, h, itemH, txtSize) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.itemH = itemH;
    this.txtSize = txtSize;
    this.arrwX = this.x + this.w;
    this.arrwY = this.y;
    this.arrwH = this.h;
  }

  press(mx, my) {
    // arrow touches
    if ((mx >= this.arrwX) && (mx <= this.arrwX+this.arrwH) && (my >= this.arrwY) && (my <= this.arrwY+this.arrwH)) {
      if (drop == true) {
        drop = false;
      } else {
        drop = true;
      }
    } // list touches
    if (drop) {
      if (items.length > 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
          if ((mx >= this.x) && (mx <= this.x + this.w) && (my >= itemY[j] ) && (my <= itemY[j] + this.itemH)) {
            selectedItem = j;
            drop = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  displayFieldString(title) {
    fill(255); // background color
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    fill(0); // text color
    textSize(this.txtSize);
    text(title, this.x + 10, this.y + this.txtSize);
  }

  display() {
    if (selectedItem == -1) {
      this.displayFieldString("Select item:");
    } else {
      this.displayFieldString(items[selectedItem]);
    }
    // arrow
    fill(255); // arrow background color
    rect(this.arrwX, this.arrwY, this.arrwH, this.arrwH);
    fill(0, 255, 0); // arrow color
    triangle(this.arrwX+5, this.arrwY+5, this.arrwX+this.arrwH-5, this.arrwY+5, this.arrwX+this.arrwH/2, this.arrwY+this.arrwH-5);
    // listItems
    if ((items.length > 0) && (drop)) {
      for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        itemY[j] = (this.y + this.h) + j*this.itemH;
        fill(255);
        rect(this.x, itemY[j], this.w, this.itemH);
        fill(0);
        textSize(this.txtSize);
        text(items[j], this.x + 10, itemY[j] + this.txtSize);
      }
    }
    if (!drop) {
      rect(this.x, this.y + this.h, this.w, 0);
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 400);
  list = new List(100, 100, 120, 24, 24, 16);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  list.display();
}

function mousePressed() {
  list.press(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```